# Modify custom properties of pdf document using VBScript

Tags: pdf, vbscript, dsofile

How can I modify PDF document's custom properties (metadata) using VBScript?

Is there a way to utilize iTextSharp from VBScript? Or should I use a different tool?  I have tried MS OLE File Property reader :

```
Option Explicit
Set oFile = CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
oFile.Open("C:\Test\312651.pdf")
oFile.CustomProperties.Add "Version", "2.0.0.0"
oFile.Save
oFile.Close
```

Got an error: ActiveX component cannot create an object 'DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties'

Comment: Did you download [dsofile.dll](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224351) and register it by using `regsvr32 dsofile.dll`?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I got a message that it registered successfully, so I am puzzled as to why it is not working

Comment: Are you on 64-bit Windows? If so, run your script using the 32-bit script host from `C:\windows\syswow64`.

Comment: Yes, I am on the 64-bit and I tried running my script from C:\Windows\SysWow64 and got the same error